# Why property is same while inherit abc.ABC class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums

I am use python3.8 and I create two services(`ForwarderService`, `LogService`) ,But it confused me why the two service type is the same and how solve it?

---

**The Code**

```py
from enum import Enum, auto
import abc

class ServiceType(Enum):
    Forwarder = auto
    Log = auto

class Service(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    @property
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def type(self) -> ServiceType:pass


class ForwarderService(Service):
    @property
    def type(self) -> ServiceType:
        return ServiceType.Forwarder

class LogService(Service):
    @property
    def type(self) -> ServiceType:
        return ServiceType.Log


s1 = ForwarderService()
s2 = LogService()

print(s1.type, s2.type)
```

**The Result**

ServiceType.Forwarder ServiceType.Forwarder

---

I want `s1.type` is `ServiceType.Forwarder` and `s2.type` is `ServiceType.Log` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo:

```
class ServiceType(Enum):
    Forwarder = auto
    Log = auto
```

Should be:

```
class ServiceType(Enum):
    Forwarder = auto()
    Log = auto()
```

Otherwise, it interprets it as the *same value*, in which case, you end up with only one enum object for the enum type, with `Log` acting as an alias.

So, consider:

```
>>> from enum import Enum
>>> class Foo(Enum):
...     bar = 0
...     baz = 0
...
>>> list(Foo)
[<Foo.bar: 0>]
>>> Foo.baz
<Foo.bar: 0>
```

Comment: Thanks, I had forget to use `auto()` ^^.